# Параметризация метода интерфейса

Tags: java

В классе Stream есть метод map `<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T, ? extends R> mapper);`
Он возвращает объекты типа Stream, но я не могу понять, что означает  перед возвращаемым типом (в целом в подобных методах такая параметризация непонятна).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<R>` перед возвращаемым типом означает как бы введение для метода нового параметризованного типа (обобщения, дженерика) - так мы как бы заявляем компилятору *"эй, я тут планирую использовать новый дженерик, о котором текущий класс еще не знает"*.
О дженерике `<T>` метод уже знает, потому что сам класс `Stream`, которому принадлежит этот метод, объявлен как параметризованный с этим дженериком - `Stream<T>`.
Если такое новое обозначение не ввести, то компилятор не поймет, что обозначает буква "R" в объявленном аргументе метода, ведь класса с таким именем компилятор (скорее всего) не найдет.

Сам метод `map` работает как преобразователь: у нас есть стрим неких данных типа `T`, в метод `map` мы передаем функцию преобразования этого типа данных в тип `R`, и метод возвращает нам стрим данных типа `R`.

Пример:

```
Stream<String> strings = Stream.of("1", "2", "3");
Stream<Integer> ints = strings.map(Integer::valueOf);
```